# How To Reset Size On drillUpButton Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Using highcharts with the drilldown.js module I can set a new chart height:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            click: function (event) {
                if (event.point.drilldown != null) {
                    var thisChart = this.chart;
                    thisChart.setSize(565, 700, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, how to revert this size change when we drill back up? I do not see and event hook on the [`drillUpButton`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown.drillUpButton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use drilldown and drillup events for a chart, not point click. See docs:

- [drilldown](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown)
- [drillup](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drillup)

Comment: Okay, closer. But the chart on drillUp does not look like it did before (http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/99yVu/6/). I need to capture the original chart layout somehow for `this` in the `drillup` event?

Comment: It looks like bug, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2898). Thanks! Possible workaround will be to set extremes directly after setting size.

Comment: I can do the setExtremes() in this example as there are only 2 categories in the main chart. But, I will not always have 2. Attempted to setExtremes(0, 1) and it still fails. It turns out it is due to the xAxis.minRange setting defaulting to 5. Why this works on init load with only 2 is interesting. Here is updated jsFiddle with working reset of chart on drillUp: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/99yVu/8/

Comment: It's defaulting to 5 because of new categories on xAxis after drilldown, I guess. Indeed, you are right, setting `minRange: 1` will resolve that issue: http://jsfiddle.net/99yVu/9/

Comment: Still think it is a bug or at least an unexpected result. I wont always have 2 initial categories so I am going to have to get category count (0 based) and apply to xAxis. Not hard, just not expected.

Comment: I totally agree. That's why I reported bug on a github :)